Cinnamon like behavior on moving and maximzing windows on kwin
So, in Cinnamon there is this keybind where Meta + Up fits the window on top like kwin, but if you press it again it will maximize the current window and if you press it another time, it goes back like kwin does.
Is it possible to achive this "double keybind/behaivour" in kwin? Or is it only a feature to the Cinnamon Deskop?
